# update from .net core 3.1 to 5.0 enitity framework breaks with This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework

I'm trying to update .net core version from `3.1` to `5.0` and that requires EF update as well. As I understand there are some breaking changes and my code stops working with exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 11. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.

> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteValueReader.GetInt64(Int32 ordinal)

> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteValueReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)

> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)

> ....

> at EdelweiessWeb.Controllers.ManagementCompaniesController.GetDisclosuresForCompany(Int32 managmentCompaniesId) in D:\Sources\edelweiess\EdelweiessWeb\Controllers\ManagementCompaniesController.cs:line 233

The code at 233th line is as follow

```cs
    private async Task<Disclosures[]> GetDisclosuresForCompany(int managmentCompaniesId)
    {
      return await m_DbContext.Disclosures
        //.Where((e) => e.Enabled
        //&& e.ManagementCompaniesId == managmentCompaniesId
        //&& !e.Deleted)
        .ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

It does not work in the new version regadles with or without `where`. It worked with v3.1 and it doesn't work with v5.0.

the SQL statement that EF executes is

```
SELECT 
  "d"."DisclosuresID", 
  "d"."Caption", 
  "d"."CompanySectionsID", 
  "d"."ContentType", 
  "d"."DateAccessible", 
  "d"."DateCreated", 
  "d"."DatePublished", 
  "d"."Deleted", 
  "d"."Description", 
  "d"."Details", 
  "d"."Enabled", 
  "d"."FundSectionsID", 
  "d"."FundsID", 
  "d"."ManagementCompaniesID", 
  "d"."MD5", 
  "d"."OrderNr", 
  "d"."Size"
FROM "Disclosures" AS "d";
```

NB: `at ordinal 11` is the filed `FundSectionsID` is nullable and is int? in c#

Please direct me where to look.

**update**
fileds are participating in a relation and therere one need to add `IsRequires(false)` to `entity.Property()`.

Comment: Your update, is that the answer?

Comment: The **update** note has really solved the problem. My model is described in fluent API and optional fields also participate in foreign key relations. v5 now wants to be infomed that is the case. Otherwise it consider fields as required (NOT NULL) event for int? .net types

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your  existing database error. It can happen if your Disclosure class has integer property , but the same column is nullable and one or more  records of your db  contains null column value. Compare class and table and delete or fix manually null value in db.